# Unable to find image latest locally

Tags: docker

When I run `docker ps` I can see the following image running:

```
6ec29fa046f0
```

But when I do `docker run -i 6ec29fa046f0`:

```
Unable to find image '6ec29fa046f0:latest' locally
Pulling repository docker.io/library/6ec2af9064f0
docker: Error: image library/6ec29fa046f0:latest not found.
```

So how can I see this image in `docker ps` but I can't run it locally?

Comment: can you post `docker ps -a` and `docker images` what is the `CMD` of the image?

Answer (score 5):

What you are **seeing is the identifier of a running container started from an image**.

You can see the images by running:

```
    docker images
```

You can also check what image is that container using by issuing:

```
    docker inspect <identifier>
```

Comment: How is this relevant to my question?

Comment: A running/stopped docker container and a docker image are two different things and have different identifiers. You can only run a container starting from an image, eg docker run nginx:latest, but you can't run. A container from a start container.

Comment: You can however commit a container so that it becomes an image that you can further run

Comment: @sergiu, I suggest you to integrate the answer with your comment in reply ton@octavian - just for better readability.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `docker ps` you can see the name or ID of the image.
In your case, this is ID of the image.

[image: docker ps]

To find the name of the image you can try to use `docker images | grep "your_id"`

[image]